# Most stable/efficient method for OpenStack deployment using Debian

Tags: debian, ansible, puppet, openstack, maas

I was wondering witch method to use to deploy OpenStack. I read [guides](https://docs.openstack.org/wallaby/deploy/index.html) of OpenStack, but there is no focusing on Debian.

What is the most stable method to deploy OpenStack on Debian?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Debian OpenStack packaging team (mostly Thomas Goirand) provide [an OpenStack cluster installer](https://salsa.debian.org/openstack-team/debian/openstack-cluster-installer); the instructions discuss Buster from when it was in development, but the packages are all available in Debian 11 (the current stable release, Bullseye) too.

See also [the OpenStack page on the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/OpenStack), and [the package tracker for all OpenStack packages](https://qa.debian.org/developer.php?email=team%2Bopenstack%40tracker.debian.org).

(I’m aware this is a link-only answer, but the instructions are far too complex to copy into an answer, and since they’re part of the packages involved, if they disappear that means the packages are gone too.)

Comment: thanks,what about official method by openstack?

Comment: What about them?